# How to integrate the absolute value of the difference between two piecewise functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have a question about doing the integration of $|f(x) - g(x)|$, where $$f(x)  =\begin{cases} 1,& \text{ if $x\geqslant0$}\\  0,& \text{if $x < 0$} \end{cases},$$ 
$$g(x) =\begin{cases}
0 ,&\text{if $x < 0$}\\\ 1/2 ,& \text{ if $x = 0$}\\\ 1,& \text{if $x > 0$} .
\end{cases}$$
 I want to evaluate the integral of $|f(x) - g(x)|$, and I try to separate the integral for three intervals, and I think I should do some real analysis here, but I am not sure because $g(0) = 1/2$ but $f(0) = 1$. Can u give me some advice of separating this integral?

Comment: Note the the value at one point does not affect the value of the integral, so you need not worry about the values $g(0)$ and $f(0)$. Instead, consider the values $|f(x)-g(x)|$ on the intervals $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: May I ask what is special about the interval (-1,0)  and (0,1)?

Comment: Those are the intervals on which at least one of $f$ and $g$ are non-zero. Everywhere else on $\mathbb R$ the quantity $|f(x)-g(x)|$ is identically zero.